# In Java, what would be an easy way to number objects?

Tags: java

e.g

the first object created knows that it is "object 1" when created.

the second object created knows that it is "object 2" when created etc.

Comment: Are you talking about variable names? Could you please give an example?

Comment: Keep a static `int` variable in the class, increment it every time the constructor is called and assign its current value to a non-static variable.

Comment: How about using an array or list?

Comment: Maybe you can use `hashCode()`? We need a bit more context here.

Comment: Correct, not talking about variable names, just simple incrementation. I'll give it a try Federico, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on the use-case, and the following is probably *not* a good solution for most of them.

But in general you can use a static member variable and increment it in the constructur:

```
public class Example {
    private static int counter = 0;
    private final int id;

    public Example() {
        id = counter++;
    }
}
```

Note that this also causes synchronisation problems once your application is multi-threaded: in general it is *not safe* to update this static variable concurrently. To fix this would require either using a `synchronized` method to increment the variable, or declaring it as an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Shouldn't the object have a variable for itself that shows the id when it was created? That does seem to be OP's question after all

Comment: @RoboMop Uh, yes, of course — my mistake. See update.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Didn't see the update, my bad

Comment: @RoboMop Not at all, the update came *after* your comment.

Comment: This works, but is not thread-safe. You can make it thread-safe by using an `AtomicInteger` for the counter.

Comment: A Q&A from 2014 gives the thread-safe solution.  See dup link.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an internal static counter(nextId) as asequence generator and an instance field to keep the value per object:

```
public class OrderedObject {
    private static int nextId=1;
    private int id=nextId++;
    
    public int getOrder() {
        return id;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "OrderedObject-"+id;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(new OrderedObject());
        System.out.println(new OrderedObject());
        System.out.println(new OrderedObject());
    }
    
}
```